# Markpoint symbol echarts

Tags: javascript, echarts

**Problem**

I use echarts to generates some graphs and I want to add symbols for certain events, I did it for min and max values of my chart however it give a symbol by default I was wondering whether I can change this symbol to another one or even add my own symbols.

**My Attempt**

I used this in my code:

```js
      markPoint: {
        data: [
          { type: 'max', name: 'Max' },
          { type: 'min', name: 'Min' }
        ]
      }
```

It looks like this

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking up some example I found out that doing something like this could solve the problem:

```js
      markPoint: {
        data: [
        { type: 'max', symbol: 'circle', name: 'Max' },
        { type: 'min', symbol: 'circle', name: 'Min' }
        ]
      }
```

for the symbol types available I tried: 'circle'-'rect'-'triangle'. However, I couldn't find a way to add my own symbol and use it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuhoS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can choose from different icon types provided by ECharts or use an image URL, a dataURI or a vector path. You can also change symbolSize, symbolRotation, etc. The [ECharts documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.markPoint) is pretty good.

Using your example, it could look something like this:

```
markPoint: {
    data: [
    { type: 'max', symbol: 'image://data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7', name: 'Max' },
    { type: 'min', symbol: 'roundRect', name: 'Min' }
    ]
  }
```

[Here is the above code on a normal bar chart](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar1&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWtJgDYFMBcya6GOAHmAQOQBKAhhNAGa1ZawBuAzrAKLu0hgAJ1qQYlADRF0nAK4AjMGQqxKAMVoBrHLAAio2pSIBfKejDBgWSCAKpiGIRADmznEKq1SETkfSmiXDdoABM7aVgQgwIAbRp6JhYsSVU-AWFRKGhKAF0TMwxLLHlgUnCHTgALYAB3AjAhWRwC9EYcUVkhfEIHdCiwWgA1CBw65Fgq2vrG5tgu2hCAeWgsAE8CZixOHQDe2ABbWmcIAGMAFVWQbqQJ6rGGpokMS-64rAYcFMp5WiFc2F2vS6nAsXTstymjiaAJaxE4tHYOAAgpwAJKHNzgyb3GYAiLGfJEE4sE6yLC0eS4aaPIikJHeTixCL2XpgF5UYlKZzCVaSCLoAD0AtgIC6YEg7gAtC5oMIcPzItFYHEAFK0bJPdQ4eRfACyvy-SNFetovM1KtkGtUFuSmqRsmcXwAyjgQF9FicwF8AHLAdhfXQ4E65fFEHIFVb0nxMhwshxsq5UfhYJp-YgE9DhojbJw4RnK5kK6C0fbdeIMTa2hUJss_P6wvpKmIK9AAJgAdAAGJ4AFnbAE4ngB2LtPVsAZnbrbHAFZ2wA2Yfz9tDp4ARnHc8XsDX84709g44729bndHsGXPaek_HCqze0OQk0AAVgAwVHHev1aDG9sQbjWVCHKQKTFqWVD6iBTycKs-wlFgVAQBi-BCt-eBIUcOACscjAANw_Ns85XtQnZYAA4osuhYJUPBIkiACKSK6oxSKLNQAAS7GLIMToANKyCEjCLGSQhOosIDjgA6osqy6AAWrI870SE7AAMInJUz5kVYQmdsAAoABoAEKcAKjDejUjAAFZyZ2jBCFg44CgAXqsQ5CkKNR0d5Pm-X5_kBYFQWBap7EzkZSKaHREVIgAMn5jExXRgyDKiqliXJZFYKpjHAJwKrzvsshDowECrHJOC8QAjt6vFnMA9FkbonC6gAHJUEW6M4ACqBnAGRSIQFVlROuwIAzox0D0bxZGoj1lQ1Go3UAJqxapgy6GoqlCLx3U8GuWBGQiSLDGoqJUWc6LyLxqkzmR-yth1nZOodqlGcxEBGZ23VWaijFDpQMItv-zyJqo-wMKBJZlrqkPQbB8FUEIwCWiE1BBl6eJ_rAeR7ICDiPposUfOUf5ocqAHsqoCLuJhUPgaoSLsI6AK470GbprCn7oGBZZpIIIhiBq1ZU98BoNoqAy_nsx5PHOg6wP256tpeY6tSuw5nquO5Dlu66tfuvbq9ra7q61TzLt2sAdreez3r0hOvu-pN7OTzbY-gNy8xBXgpMmTQEKbhuwHSDIENrkZhzurXjkDHvjN7qiw1a_vdDbTyh9GO5rk8kdZ7HHN2wq-PEITxPQNcwNu5TYOUDTIhuPTZZMyzxhsw4hdYzjKDGLhQA)